# PhP adding arrays to arrays from hidden fields

Tags: php, arrays, hidden-field

I am trying to add values to an array in php through an HTML form and hidden fields. First I get the values from the posts in my php file and then I add the values to the array like so on index.php:

```
<?php
    $gamelist = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gamelist',FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    $key = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gameID', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $team1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'teamID1', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $team2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'teamID2', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $date = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'date');

if ($gamelist === NULL) {
    $gamelist = array();


    }

    if ($new_game === NULL) {
    $new_game = array();


    }   


//get action variable from POST
$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');

//initialize error messages array
$errors = array();

//process
switch( $action ) {
    case 'Add Game':



        $new_game[] = $date;
        $new_game[] = $team1;
        $new_game[] = $team2;


        $gamelist[] = $new_game;

        break;
    case 'Delete Game':
        $game_index = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gameID', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if ($game_index === NULL || $game_index === FALSE) {
            $errors[] = 'The game cannot be deleted.';
        } else {
            unset($gamelist[$game_index]);
            $gamelist = array_values($gamelist);
        }
        break;


}

include('gamelist.php');
?>
```

The output for this code is this below. This is exactly what I want.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2/30/15
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```

However, when another game is added (when another array is added to $gamelist[]) the array forgets the previous array and turns into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5/17/2015
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

I need the [0] array to still have the values i passed to it before.

Any Ideas???

This below is the complete html side (gamelist.php) with hidden fields:

```
    <?php

require('../database.php');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM team_table';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$teams = $statement->fetchAll();
$team = $statement->fetch();
$statement->closeCursor();
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RP LL Game List</title>



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>RP LL Game List</h1>
</header>
<main>


<!-- Dumping gamelist and errors arrays -->





    <h2>Errors:</h2>
<?php if (count($errors) == 0) : ?>
<p>There are no errors</p>
    <?php else: ?>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach($errors as $error) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?></ul>
<?php endif; ?>


<h2>Games:</h2>
<?php if (count($gamelist) == 0) : ?>  
    <p>There are no games in the game list.</p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <ul>
            <?php print_r($gamelist); ?>

                <?php foreach($gamelist as $game)  : ?> 

                        <li><?php print_r($game); ?></li> 
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<br>

<!-- Add Game Form -->

<h2>Add Game:</h2>
    <form action="." method="post" > 
        <?php foreach( $gamelist as $game ) : ?>
<input type="hidden" name="gamelist[]" value="<?php echo $game; ?>">
<?php print_r($gamelist); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>






        <label>Team1:</label>
        <select  name="teamID1">
            <?php foreach ($teams as $team) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $team['team_id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $team['name_col']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            </select><br>

        <label>Team2:</label>
        <select  name="teamID2">
            <?php foreach ($teams as $team) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $team['team_id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $team['name_col']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            </select><br>

        <label>Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="date">


<input type="submit" name="action" value="Add Game">
</form>
<br>


<?php if (count($gamelist) > 0 && empty($game_to_modify)) : ?>
<h2>Select game:</h2>
<form action="." method="post" >
<?php foreach( $gamelist as $key => $game ) : ?>
<input type="hidden" name="gamelist[]" 
 value="<?php print_r($game[$key]); ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>



<label>Game:</label>
<select name="gameID">
<?php foreach( $gamelist as $key => $game ) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo $game[$key]; ?>">
    <?php echo $game; ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>



<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete Game">




</form>
<?php endif; ?>



</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your complete code. It's not possible that your array has two values with this code. You must be initializating/storing $gamelist somewhere else and that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: Complete code posted.

Answer (score 0):

every time you are submitting the form the values vl not be populated,instead try to use session so that you can have previous values in your desired array